# How to pass session value in a query from .aspx code?

Tags: asp.net, sql, linq

I want to pass session value from .aspx code , i.e the source code of the web

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT Album.AlbumID, Album.DefaultPhotID, Album.AlbumName, PhotAlbum.Photo FROM Album INNER JOIN PhotAlbum ON Album.DefaultPhotID = PhotAlbum.PhotoID where userid=<%  Session["UserId"] %>">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I am doubtful if this code will work.

Comment: I think you must exclude `Session["UserId"]` from double quotes, and use with "+" sign, like string concatenation

Comment: Have you tried to see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SessionParameter` with `SelectParameters` to pass `Session` values

**[MSDN Doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sessionparameter.aspx)**

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT Album.AlbumID, Album.DefaultPhotID, Album.AlbumName, PhotAlbum.Photo FROM Album INNER JOIN PhotAlbum ON Album.DefaultPhotID = PhotAlbum.PhotoID where userid=@userid">
<SelectParameters>
         <asp:SessionParameter Name="userid" Type="String"  SessionField="UserId" />
</SelectParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
```